# Notification for internet connection in Mac OS X cocoa application

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

In my app I want to notify the user for any internet notifications such as switching from ethernet to wifi or no reachability in System it has to automatically notify my app. I know how to do in iphone app using reachability example but the same doesnt work for Mac OS X Cocoa app. How to implement this using Objective-C in my cocoa app?

Answer (score 1):

Reachability exists on Mac just like iOS. Some of the flags are a little different, but the basic approach is the same. See [SimpleReach](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SimpleReach/Introduction/Intro.html).

Comment: thanks rob.....got it to work.....just adjust the flags in reachability and it works well for MAC OSX too.....